# What are all the entities that are induced by ones kula (कुल)?

Tags: scripture, gods, caste-system, terminology, varnashrama

The word कुल is used across scriptures in different contexts. I am using the meaning of family here. Many entities are induced in an individual born in a kula.

I want to know all the entities that are induced by the caste in an individual. The following are the few I heard of

1. कुलाचार (Kula-Acharas): Practices or customs of a caste.
2. कुलवृत्ति (kula-Vritti): Profession or karma of the caste.
3. कुलदेवी/कुलदेवता (kula-Devi/ kula-Devatha): God/Goddesses of the caste.

The first one tells the individual of a caste, all the rules and regulations (constitution) she needs to abide by for daily life. The second one tells her the profession in which she needs to contribute to society. The third one tells the name of the god or goddesses she needs to pray to and offer.

So, if one takes birth in a particular kula, she gets all the three entities afaik. Are there any other entities that an individual gets by default along with the kula?

Comment: Kula in Lalita Sahsranama has deep Yogic/Tantric meaning ... it is not talking about family there .. In Shaktism Shiva is known as Akula (opposite of Kula) and Kula is Parashakti

Comment: @Rickross Yeah true. I think it is referring to collection of chakras. But I just quoted for the usage of word.

Comment: Yes alright .... @hanugm